# Performing a document upload in PHP not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

Currently I'm using codeigniter 3.0 and I have a multiple document upload tab in my add page that should upload 1 document each, but the user has the option to click add to insert another document. Here the user can write the title of the document and upload a document and they can select the add button to add more documents. But I cannot store these document in my database when I click on the save button. Here is my current code:

View class:

```
<td><input type="text" name="doctitle[]" placeholder="Title"></td>
<td><input type="file" name="documents[]"></td>
<td><a class="btn btn-success" id="addobj" href="javascript:void(0)">Add </a></td>
```

Controller Class:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $main['page'] = 'crm/listings/add';
            $this->load->view('crm/index', $main);
        }else {  
            $maindata=array('clients_id'=>$this->session->userdata('clientsessid'));
            $insertid=$this->listings_model->insert_listing($maindata);
            
            if($insertid){
                if ($this->input->post('documents')) {
                    $documentPost = $this->input->post('documents');
                    $documentTitle = $this->input->post('doctitle');
                    $documentArray = array();
                    $c = 0;
                    foreach($documentPost as $dp){
                        if($this->web_upload->do_upload('documents'))
                            { 
                                $filedata=$this->web_upload->data();
                                $dp=$filedata['file_name'];
                            }  
                        $documentArray[$c]['listings_id']= $insertid;
                        $documentArray[$c]['title']= $documentTitle;
                        $documentArray[$c]['document']= $dp;
                        $documentArray[$c]['added_date']=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                        $documentArray[$c]['added_by']= $this->session->userdata('user_id');
                        $c++;
                    }

                    if(count($documentArray) > 0){
                        $this->listings_model->save_document($documentArray);
                    }
                }
                redirect('listings/sales');
               }
```

Model Class:

```
function save_document($maindata){
    $this->db->insert_batch("crm_property_docs",$maindata); 
    print_r($this->db->last_query()); die();
    return $this->db->insert_id(); 
}

function insert_listing($maindata){
    $this->db->insert("crm_listings",$maindata);
    $prime=$this->db->insert_id();
    return $prime;
}
```

Now I have added a `print_r($this->db->last_query()); die();` statement in my save_document model so if it is being executed it should end the process there but it doesnt end my process, it just fills in all the data values in my database except for the documents data, which means this model is never being called and I'm not sure if I'm using the right method to upload these documents in my database.

Comment: `$notesArray`, where does it come from? does it hold any data?

Comment: Sorry typo on my part, it's `$documentArray`